# Receiving 403 instead of 404 when calling non existing endpoint

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

This is a typical part of Spring Security configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().and().cors().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

I have a problem with `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()`.

After adding it, when I call non-existing endpoints, for example: **GET: /api/v1/not-existing**, I receive **403** instead of expected **404** response.

I want to protect all my resources but I want to get 404 when calling not existing resources.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am okay with this behaviour . If an user is not authenticated , why bother to worry about telling him more information about your system. Just like if an user does not have permission to view your harddisk , why need to let him can discover your harddisk directory tree structure .

If you really want to return 404 , you need to customize `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and `AccessDeniedHandler` in the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` . Both of them will be invoked if an user does not have enough permission to visit an endpoint (i.e. `AccessDeniedException` happen). The former is for the anonymous user and the latter is for the non-anonymous user (i.e. user that is authenticated successfully but without enough permission)

Both of their default implementation (i.e `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint` and `AccessDeniedHandlerImpl`) simply return 403 now . You have to customize them such that they will first check if there are existing endpoints to serve the current `HttpServletRequest` and return 404 if no. You can do it by looping through the `HandlerMapping` inside the `DispatcherServlet` and check if any of the `HandlerMapping` can handle the current `HttpServletRequest`.

First create an object that do this check :

```java
public class HttpRequestEndpointChecker {

    private DispatcherServlet servlet;

    public HttpRequestEndpointChecker(DispatcherServlet servlet) {
        this.servlet = servlet;
    }

    public boolean isEndpointExist(HttpServletRequest request) {

        for (HandlerMapping handlerMapping : servlet.getHandlerMappings()) {
            try {
                HandlerExecutionChain foundHandler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
                if (foundHandler != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then customize `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and `AccessDeniedHandler` to use this object for checking :

```java
public  class MyAccessDeniedHandler extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl {
    private HttpRequestEndpointChecker endpointChecker;

    public MyAccessDeniedHandler(HttpRequestEndpointChecker endpointChecker) {
        this.endpointChecker = endpointChecker;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (!endpointChecker.isEndpointExist(request)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "Resource not found");
        } else {
            super.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint extends Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint {

        private HttpRequestEndpointChecker endpointChecker;

        public MyAuthenticationEntryPoint(HttpRequestEndpointChecker endpointChecker) {
            this.endpointChecker = endpointChecker;
        }

        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
            if (!endpointChecker.isEndpointExist(request)) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "Resource not found");
            } else {
                super.commence(request, response, authException);
            }
        }
}
```

And configure them :

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;

    @Autowired
    private HttpRequestEndpointChecker endpointChecker;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            ..............
            ..............
            http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new MyAuthenticationEntryPoint(endpointChecker))
                .accessDeniedHandler(new MyAccessDeniedHandler(endpointChecker));

    }

    @Bean
    public HttpRequestEndpointChecker endpointChecker() {
        return new HttpRequestEndpointChecker(dispatcherServlet);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have always though that default behaviour is 404 and not 403, isn't it?... :o And that it's something unusual that I return 403.

Comment: Depend on how you view it . I prefer to return 403 in this case with the reasons that I mentioned in the answer. I feel it is very natural and very make sense

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your only option is the following:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().and().cors().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(all-your-endpoints).authenticated();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

You need to replace `all-your-endpoints` with a regex or multiple regex that match all your endpoints. In fact, you can even get rid of `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll();` unless you really want to be explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, where I was getting 403 for any url.
After a while I found out the with the spring update from 1.5.x to something later, the way to declare the contextPath changed. So Spring could not resolve my url because I had wrong declaration on my application.yml

It changed from:

```
server:
  contextPath: /app-name
```

To:

```
server:  
  servlet:
    contextPath: /app-name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define /error in the `SecurityFilterChain` to get this behavior

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> {
                    requests.requestMatchers("/public-end-points/**","/error").permitAll();
                    requests.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```