# HttpSecurity..authorizeHttpRequests() is not working properly

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I need a "/public" endpoint be accessed by unauthenticated users and any other endpoints be accessed by only authenticated users. Why this configuration doesn't work. I configured it according to spring security 6 authorication docs.
When I access "/public" it responses with `401 Unauthorized`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(a ->
                a.requestMatchers("/public").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add a `@Bean` annotation to `filterChain`. I provided a answer, can you try it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of `SecurityFilterChain` that you have should be:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(a -> {
      a.requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll(); // for all paths that start with `/public/..`
      a.anyRequest().authenticated();
    });

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't still work :(

Comment: I checked .authorizeHttpRequests() is invoked.

Comment: Are you login with Basic Auth/ or Bearer token ? Also is it all your security config chain ?

Comment: There is only one security config. I created a plain project with just spring boot entry point and signle configuration to make sure other components don't affect to .authorizeHttpRequests() method. But it doesn't work anyways.

Comment: May I contact you via telegram or something to share the plain project with two classes so that you can point out where is the issue. Or there is a way to send it here?

Comment: You can share here the github repository(link) to the project  and i will check and give an answer here.

Comment: I created the controller to handle this endpoint. This endpoint is now access with 200 OK. But why if there are no appropriate handlers it sends 403 Forbidden instead of 404 Not found by default?

Comment: i cannot say you why, because i dont see the code. Your main problem was in " "/public" endpoints responses with 401 Unauthorized", and i am sure that my answer solved the problem. About 403 instead of 404, I think it`s is an topic for another question or you can find something similar why it happen.

Comment: Creating an appropriate handler that handles this endpoint solves this problem.
https://github.com/Denis3432522/test-spring-security-project/tree/master
Could you check the project please?

Comment: yep, i checked. This is expected behavior to prevent leakage of path info. Have a look at this answer [receiving-403-instead-of-404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70054528/receiving-403-instead-of-404-when-calling-non-existing-endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

that only happens in Spring Security versions above 6.1.2. If you switch to Spring Boot 3.1.2, your configuration will be correct and it will work.